# Import .pdf_tex images

Tags: graphics, include

For importing pdf images `\includegraphics` works withouth any problem.

Now, in the same document I need to import `pdf_tex`.

I am using this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\input{imagenes/image.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It returns:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `image.pdf' not found.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.106 ...cs[width=\unitlength,page=28]{image.pdf}}
%
Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

What can I do?

Comment: it's a tex file `\input` it not `\includegraphics` also do not use the `minipage` (which is not doing anything)` (it is simplest if it is in the same document so that the internal reference to the graphic works)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried with `\input` as is written at the end of the post; and need `minipage` to add a short note below the image..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: Good, I have changed that, but doesn't produce the image..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: But I have showed it..@DavidCarlisle. It is at the end of the post

Comment: as I said in the initial comment it's easiest if you use `\input{image.pdf_tex}` with `image.pdf_tex` and `image.pdf` in the same directory as your document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65200/discussion-between-hernan-miraola-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: yeah, but as I have answered the question I thought maybe there will be a better one..@samcarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `image.pdf_tex` uses `\includegraphics{image.pdf}`, so if `image.pdf` is not placed on main directory (where `main.tex` is) Latex finds no file.

The easiest way to fix the problem is to place `image.pdf_tex` and `image.pdf` where `main.tex` is.

The resulting code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{image.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

To scale the image you can use  `\def\svgwidth{<desired width>}` inside `figure` environment